# Javascript tooltip unexpected text wrapping (Tooltipster)

Tags: javascript, tooltipster

I'm using the javascript library [tooltipster](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/) and I don't know why the text is wrapping in the tooltip box.

[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="spanBackground" style="background: rgba(238, 0, 140, 120);" 
 class="tooltipjs" title="Touch to interact">
```

Javascript:

```
function AnimateUpDown(toolTipElement) {
        $(toolTipElement).animate({ top: '+=20' }, 1000);
        $(toolTipElement).animate({ top: '-=20' }, 1000, AnimateUpDown);
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.tooltipjs')
            .tooltipster(
            {
                animation: 'grow',
                arrow: false,
                //Custom trigger effectively disables the default onhover trigger
                trigger: 'custom',
                functionReady: function (instance, helper) {
                    AnimateUpDown(helper.tooltip);
                }

            });
        toolTipOpenAndClose();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue about that, that's the first place to check. Should be fixed in a few days. https://github.com/iamceege/tooltipster/issues/600